# VF Page - get the previous page URL to redirect back

Tags: visualforce

I have overridden detail and edit pages of an object. So to override, the save functionality or the delete functionality - I need to redirect the user back to the page from where she came from. So in my VF page how do I get back the return URL. I want to do redirect from the controller using pageReference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click overriden button and look at your URL, you will see:

```
apex/yorpage?id=00136000002lG0u for detail
apex/yorpage?retURL=%2F00136000002lG0u for edit
```

So in your controller read this parameter:

```
returnURL = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); or
returnURL = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL');
```

And after everything is complete do return:

```
return new PageReference('/'+returnURL);
```

Comment: You can also use StandardController's `cancel` function, which basically has the same behavior of determining which parameter should be used.